# async_read() of a maximum size

Tags: c++, boost, asyncsocket

I have an issue with `boost::async_read()`.
Online, I found that there is a function `read_at_least(n)`. But I'm looking for a function like `read_max()` which would read a maximum amount of bytes.

The thing is that I have different structures to read, each of them beginning by the size of the structure itself.
I would like to be able to do things like :

```
int s = async_read([...], read_at_least(4), read_max(4));
async_read([...], read_at_least(s), read_max(s));
```

The problem of not doing this is that I have to store the rest of the read operation in cases it reads for more than I wanted.

Thank you in advance,
Florian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/transfer_exactly.html), basically, provide a completion condition to the read operation where you specify exactly the number of bytes you want to read.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find this in the documentation. I'll try this !